# How to create Message Box with Textfield using Cocos2d-x (Android)

Tags: android, popup, cocos2d-x, textfield, messagebox

I am trying to find a way to create a pop up box or a message box on Android using Cocos2d-x that pops ups,  receives text or number input from user and do something with the input once the user presses a button to continue or proceed.

Is there a way that I can do it in cocos2d-x?
I am using cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.4

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no built-in support for what you are looking for. You have to write your own implementation and for reference you can have a look at [JACModalAlert](https://github.com/jandujar/cocos2d-x-extensions/tree/master/extensions/JACModalAlert). (However, its a little outdated and you might have to update few segments to make it work in your project).

Comment: there's no build in support at all? hmm that is inconvenient.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you need their own encapsulation, or modify the cocos2d CCMessageBox

Answer (score 0):

Easier way is to design a UI using cocosbuilder, and use it as a message box.. Let me know if you want more details on how to achieve this...